How to check whether given a filter on a csv file a product has been bought
I don't know how to make python show me once whether a certain product has been bought, because if a certain Customer ID purchases something twice it is shown twice.
I have a csv file that shows me products purchased for each customer id, and i coded the following to show me all the products that a certain Customer ID has purchased:
df.groupby(['Customer ID'] ).agg({'Product':'sum'})

The problem is that in this way it also shows me when the product has been purchased several times, for example:



Customer ID
Product




12345
PC, PC, Phone


67890
Phone, Watch Watch



I want to know if the product has been purchased, so each of them should show once, even i the customer purchased it several times, how can i do that?

First you shouldn't use sum as aggregation function it's inefficient (quadratic behavior). You could use .agg({'Product': lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())}). Alternatively, if this is the only aggregation that will be performed, drop_duplicates(subset=['Customer ID', 'Product']) before groupby.
